# How to get a single cell value of DataGrid in UWP MVVM structure

Tags: c#, uwp

[DataGrid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oydr.png)

*I need to select and display a single cell value in this DataGrid using MVVM in UWP.*
*I tried using* `SelectionChanged` *but in that entire row data will be selected.*

Comment: If you get the Datagrid column, you could get the cell content by using `DataGridColumn.GetCellContent()`. But if you can't get the Datagrid column, there is no direct way to get the cell value. What you could get is the data of the row and you need to check the cell value by yourself.

Comment: I got the data of the row, but how can I know which cell I have clicked?